# UIScrollView & UIButtons, really strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

Now that i'm implementing a UIScrollView, i'm faced of a problem that i never see : 2 of 3 UIButtons that are on my scroll view not responds at my click.
One does but the other not.

I made a lot of research, and tried a lot of things (try to cut the delays, set user interaction...)

In the viewDidLoad method :

```
BoutonPig1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[BoutonPig1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 145, 90)];
[BoutonPig1 addTarget:self action:@selector(BonusShop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIImage * boutonPig1OnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pig2ShopBloquee.png"];
[BoutonPig1 setImage:boutonPig1OnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

My set scrol view method with 3 elements :

```
-(void)setScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scroller1
{
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = scroller.frame.size.height * i;
    frame.size = scroller.frame.size;

    UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    newPageView.frame = frame;

    if (i == 0)
    {
        [newPageView addSubview:BoutonPig1];
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
        [newPageView addSubview:BoutonPig2];
    }
    if (i == 2)
    {
        [newPageView addSubview:BoutonPig3];
    }
    [newPageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scroller addSubview:newPageView];
}
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroller.frame.size.width * 3, scroller.frame.size.height);
}
```

The three elements that i put on the subview are 3 UIButtons like in the first code extract. The do the same thing. The only thing who is different now is their position.

```
    [BoutonPig2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 164, 145, 90)];
    [BoutonPig3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 285, 145, 90)];
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is the frame of your UIScrollView? Id imagine that the content size of your scrollview isn't big enough tbh.

Comment: scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(59.0, 54.0, 145, 180)];

Comment: Well there is the answer then, 180 + 54 = 234 which is greater than 285 on button 3 for starters. Debug out the frame of the scroll view. Also not sure why you need that image view as your not setting an image to it.

Comment: But the problem is now that i've changed the size of my scroll view, the buttons appeard in all the screen and not only on my scroll view :/

Comment: I don't kow how to do it whithout the image :/

Comment: well that adds to the above issue then. Your having issues with your coordinates. You dont need that additional view. Look up how to use frame and center in UIView

Comment: But how could i limit the visible size of my scroll view please ? :/

Comment: Read how frames work on UIView. You need to read the documentation.

Comment: I've read it but not fix it :/

Comment: Ok protip: set the background of your scroll view to red and see what space it takes up. You have all you need to solve this.

Comment: This is the problem, i can't fix it. The red zone makes a lot of pixes because     scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(59.0, 54.0, 145, 300)];   and not limit the visible content to 180 pixels as i tried with :     [scroller scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 180) animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in the coordinates because you add the button BoutonPig2   BoutonPig3 on newPageView with coordinates CGRectMake(0, 164, 145, 90) CGRectMake(0, 285, 145, 90) but you need to set the CGRectMake(0, 45, 145, 90) for all or CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 90)... because you dont add the buttons on scool but on the newPageView and you have new coordinates with 0,0